Staging Ground Needs Migration Option in Reasons Box
Recently the question monitoring and resubsribing aws sns alerts appeared in the Staging Ground. The bash script was complete and the question was more proper for Code Review. However, in the Review question box there is no migration option to choose when denying approval for the question, e.g.

There was a later opportunity to suggest the migration in the comment box that pops up, but that requires the reviewer to go grab the Code Review URL and format it as a markdown URL and include it in the comment. That slows the entire process down and isn't something that many reviewers will do on staging question after staging question, I did.
To make the process more efficient you should have a checkbox item for "Belongs on different Stack Exchange site" (or something similar) and then a select box of the top-10 or so other sites (you could probably do 5 or so, Super User, Unix & Linux, Ask Ubuntu, Server Fault, and Code Review, or whatever the stats show)
Just an idea for improvement, not a criticism. A check box and list of top-5 or 10 migration sites would be helpful.

Generally, other sites in the network are not happy when we send them low quality questions. Questions land in SG because they are probably low quality.

I don't see a need for a migration. An off-topic close reason saying that it's not suitable here is enough. There's no reason to send low-quality questions without answers to other sites.

What was low-quality about the question for review? It was properly formatted and complete? It just wasn't a valid question for SO. Not all questions needing migration from Staging are low-quality. Why not provide an easy way to handle those? Just presuming all questions in staging are low-quality doesn't seem like valid discussion as it assumes all questions in staging are low-quality.

We wouldn't want the regulars of other SE sites to try to judge whether questions meet Stack Overflow standards; therefore, we shouldn't try to judge questions by their standards either - including topicality. We may have a reasonable intuition about what other Stack Exchange sites exist and which may accept a question, but ultimately it's their prerogative.
Historically, question migration has not had a good track record even under the best conditions - never mind the fact that Staging Ground questions should be expected a priori to be (or at least start out) low quality. This is especially true for the Code Review site which has very specific standards for question formatting and presentation that are surprisingly different from Stack Overflow.
If a Staging Ground question is not suitable for Stack Overflow because of the subject matter, please vote correspondingly - i.e., use "Vote as off topic -> not about programming or software development". This might seem odd for questions that look like they might belong on Code Review (or Software Engineering, etc.) instead; but we define this more narrowly than one might naively assume, and expect questions to meet that narrow definition, and close them for that reason when they don't (hence the "as defined in the Help Center" text in the question closure banner).
The sorts of migration options you describe have been considered before for the main space, and repeatedly rejected (e.g.). (In fact, we don't even migrate questions to the localized sites when they appear to be about programming but written in Spanish, Portuguese, Russian or Japanese.) The reasons for this apply at least as strongly to the Staging Ground.

But leaving a comment telling OP that other sites exists and they might want to check them out is a good idea.

Now that's a valid answer. Even the mention that another site would be more proper would be helpful. At least in my mind you want to encourage use of Stack Exchange and help new users along rather than just telling them they, and their questions, are not wanted. A delicate balance.
